# SharePoint Online multiline with append - JSON formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, multiple-lines-of-text, column-formatting

In SharePoint Online I have a multiple lines of text column that has append checked.

[image: with JSON]

Instead of showing "View Entries" in multiple-line text column with append-only checked, will show all entries or only the latest entry?

[image]

I am internested in JSON only answers.